# Chart Axis won't properly display the quadrant

Tags: pgfplots, formatting

I have a graph which has data in the 4th quadrant.  Unfortunately, the visible axis orientation is such that the chart appears in the 1st quadrant.  Is there any way that I can move the x-axis to the top of the chart so the graph looks to be in the 4th quadrant.

```
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
title=Figure 2: Absorbance ($-\ln{T}$) Versus Concentration ($C$),
xlabel={$C$ [$\mu M$]},
ylabel={$-\ln{T}$},
xmin=0, xmax=11,
ymin=-5, ymax=0,
ymajorgrids=true,
legend cell align=left,
]
\addplot+[
only marks
]
table {
x      y
8.13   -2.152
6.504  -2.468
4.878  -2.986
3.252  -3.44
2.439  -3.816
1.626  -4.04
0.813  -4.312
0      -4.564
};
\addlegendentry{$-\ln{}$ of Table 1 data}

\addplot+[
mark = none,
domain = 0:11,
samples = 2
]
{.30611393146937*x-4.5298875237969};
\addlegendentry{$-\ln{T} = 0.306x - 4.530$}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
```

[image: What I don't want]

I would also prefer it if there was no interference between the `axis label`/`ticks` and the `title`.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Answer (score 1):

Some more styling and involvement:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.11}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
xmin=0, xmax=11,
ymin=-5, ymax=0,
xtick=\empty,
ytick=\empty,
legend cell align=left,
]
\addplot+[
only marks
]
table {
x      y
8.13   -2.152
6.504  -2.468
4.878  -2.986
3.252  -3.44
2.439  -3.816
1.626  -4.04
0.813  -4.312
0      -4.564
};
\addlegendentry{$-\ln{}$ of Table 1 data}

\addplot+[
mark = none,
domain = 0:11,
samples = 2
]
{.30611393146937*x-4.5298875237969};
\addlegendentry{$-\ln{T} = 0.306x - 4.530$}
\end{axis}
\begin{axis}[
title={Figure 2: Absorbance ($-\ln{T}$) Versus Concentration ($C$)},
title style={at={(0.5,1.15)}},
axis x line* =top,
axis y line* =left,
y axis line style={latex-},
x axis line style={-latex},
xlabel={$C$ [$\mu M$]},
ylabel={$-\ln{T}$},
ymajorgrids=true,
xmin=0, xmax=11,
ymin=-5, ymax=0,
]
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As per section 4.9.9 (Axis Lines) of the `pgfplots` manual, you can use the `axis x line` option to control where the *x*-axis is drawn.

For your case, add the code

```
axis x line=top
```

to the options for your `axis` environment.

Note that the default settings place axis lines around all four sides of the plot, forming a sort of border. Depending on how you want the plot to look, you can use additional options documented in section 4.9.9 to add additional axes or remove others for a consistent look.